# CloudWatch logs are not created automatically for lambdas after deployment

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, serverless

I'm deploying my `next.js` app with `@sls-next/serverless-component@1.17.0-alpha.12` to AWS lambda.
I read that logs in CloudWatch should be created automatically (and actually one time it worked fine), but when trying to view logs for lambda, I'm getting this messages:

[image]

How can I create logs for lambda? or make the `serverless-next.js` tool to create one in deployment?

Thanks!

EDIT:
lambda execution role permissions
[image]

In JSON format:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the Lambda function execution role have CloudWatch permissions? Could you post the complete execution role policy?

Comment: @Paradigm I added it to the question.  You can see that the lambda role has the right permissions.

Comment: Could you paste the JSON? That screenshot doesn't tell much.

Comment: @Paradigm Sure, added

Comment: Permissions look fine, try switching lambda execution role to another temporary role and then back again to the original one, using the console. After this, invoke the function to check if logs were created.

Comment: @Paradigm will try that now. I don't know if it's relevant but the lambdas are on Lambda@Edge.

Comment: @Paradigm I changed the role to another role and then turn it back but with no success. Now i'm trying to delete all the distributions/lambdas/roles and deploy from clean.